# Getting the format correct when writing data to a text file from a matlab script

Tags: matlab, plotly

I'm trying to write data to a text file from my matlab script. I want two columns which it gives me but I want my time variable (t) followed by my variable (x) which is my amplitude. Its outputting a file like below.

[image: Image1]

Everything is perfect however i don't believe my (t) variable is first followed by my (x) variable. I'm trying to upload this file to [ploy.ly](https://plot.ly/plot) to be graphed but when i set column 1 to my x variable and column 2 to my y variable it plots a oval like below. It's suppose to plot a sinusoidal signal.

[image: Image2]

My code is as follows:

```
f = 1E3;
T = 1/f;
tmin = 0;
tmax = 5*T;
dt = T/100;
t = tmin:dt:tmax;
x = sin(2*pi*f*t);
sinData.txt = fopen('sinData.txt','w');
fprintf(sample.txt,'%7.5f,%7.5f\r\n',x);
fclose(sinData.txt);
plot(t,x,'r');
grid on;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MATLAB writes files in column major format.  What this means is that it will traverse every row first in one column before moving to the next column.  If you have a `M x 2` matrix of values where the first column is a vector of `t` values and the second column is a vector of `x` values, try transposing the matrix before writing to file.  That way, each column represents a pair of `(t,x)` values for you and MATLAB should be able to preserve writing to the file so that each **row** is a unique pair.

Also, in your code you are only writing the `x` values to the file.  This makes sense because if you look at your text file going line by line, it pretty much mimics a sinusoidal output.  It goes from 0 up to 1, then back to 0 again.  Your `x` vector is a sinusoidal output which thus fits the pattern.  As such, you probably want to write the `t` values as well. To do this, modify the `fprintf` statement in your code so that it looks like this:

```
fprintf(sinData.txt,'%7.5f,%7.5f\r\n', [t;x]);
```

**BUG SPOT FROM RTL (Thanks!):**  Make sure you change `sample.txt` to `sinData.txt` in your `fprintf` statement as that is the name of the handle to the open file that you have opened.

Looking at your code, `t` and `x` are row vectors, so this should (hopefully) work.  I haven't tried it myself, and I'm somewhere where I don't have MATLAB accessible.  Hit me up with a comment and let me know if it works.

Comment: confirming this does work, except a typo carried forward from original code `sample.txt` should be `sinData.txt`

Comment: @rayryeng thanks this does check out. I just couldn't figure out how to add in another variable. i kept typing just t,x when I needed to include the square brackets and semicolon [t;x].

Comment: @ShaneYost: No problem.  What `[t;x]` is doing is that it is concatenating two matrices together row wise.  `t` will come first, and `x` follows it after going from top to bottom.  FWIW, if you want to concatenate two matrices **column-wise**, simply do `[t x]` or `[t,x]`.  Spaces or commas in MATLAB denote that the next element will go in the next column where semi-colons mean that the next element goes in the next row.  BTW: Just checked out your profile.  Respect for your craft, and good luck with everything!